Date Handling Issue in C# Visual Studio Chart XValue
My chart in Microsoft Forms, on Visual Studio, cannot show me the dates formatted correctly. When you put integers it works perfectly, but numbers formatted to look like dates don't work.
This is my table in SQLite with pd_data as integers.
CREATE TABLE producao
(
    pd_pr_codigo INTEGER,
    pd_data INTEGER,
    pd_codigo INTEGER,
    pd_qtd_produzida REAL,

    PRIMARY KEY (pd_pr_codigo, pd_codigo, pd_data)
    FOREIGN KEY (pd_pr_codigo) REFERENCES produtos(pr_codigo)
)

This is my code:
private void BtProdBlocos_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        try
        {
            string sql = "SELECT pd_data, pd_qtd_produzida FROM producao";
            SqliteParameter[] emptyparameter = new SqliteParameter[]{ };
            chart1.DataSource = Funcoes.Cursor(sql, emptyparameter);

            chart1.Series["Producao"].XValueMember = "pd_data"; 
            chart1.Series["Producao"].YValueMembers = "pd_qtd_produzida";

            chart1.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
}

And this is the graph, values ​​in the X integers corresponding to the dates 2024/10/22 and 2024/10/23.
Now with using pd_data as text and putting the dates like dd/mm/yyyy in SQL:
CREATE TABLE producao
(
    pd_pr_codigo INTEGER,
    pd_data TEXT,
    pd_codigo INTEGER,
    pd_qtd_produzida REAL,

    PRIMARY KEY (pd_pr_codigo, pd_codigo, pd_data)
    FOREIGN KEY (pd_pr_codigo) REFERENCES produtos(pr_codigo)
)

with the same dates, and the same code, only 1 date appears, and no matter what I do and try. I. NO. ACHIEVED. TO ARRANGE.
the table columns showing the dates are there.
I debugged the code and came to the conclusion that all the dates ​​arrive, they just don't appear in the chart correctly, for some reason. Also, Funcoes.cursor is the connection to the database. I send the SQL query through this function and it returns all the values.

What you should have done is posted your solution as an answer, instead of editing it into the question. Now that your question answers itself, its not really a question at all any more.

Your two observations are correct and known, 1: for a time based X axis to work correctly in charts in .net, you must use a DateTime data type. 2: SQL lite doesn't support datetime natively. Your title "Visual Studio Chart CANT handle dates in XValue" therefor is misleading, it does handle dates, you just didn't provide any. The solution is correct, convert the data before building the series points.

Thank you, @ChrisSchaller! Your feedback is greatly appreciated! I'm a new contributor and not a fluent English speaker, so the typos and misunderstandings were things I wasn't aware of. I'm working on fixing the question!

I was able to arrive at a solution. The value of X needed to be of type datetime in C# in order for it to be correctly understood. Since SQLite does not have a native datetime type, the solution was to transfer both values to a DataTable and within it, convert the pd_data and pd_qtd_quantidade values to datetime and double, respectively.
In the code, I also formatted the X-axis to display at a 45-degree angle for better readability, and it will show only the first and last values as optional. The only thing I was not able to change is that if there is a gap between the dates, the program fills it in (for example: from 10/11/2024 to 10/13/2024, the chart will add 10/12/2024 in between, even without a Y-value), which I personally didn’t like and would like to change, though I haven't found a solution for this yet. I hope this helps someone as well!
Here is the code:
private void BtProdBlocos_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    string comandosql = "SELECT pd_data, pd_qtd_produzida FROM producao";
    SqliteParameter[] parametrovazio = new SqliteParameter[] { };
    DataTable dataTable = Funcoes.Cursor(comandosql, parametrovazio);

    // Check if the chart has the correct series
    if (chart1.Series.Count == 0)
    {
        chart1.Series.Add("Producao");
    }

    // Configure the series
    chart1.Series["Producao"].XValueType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartValueType.DateTime;
    chart1.Series["Producao"].YValueType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartValueType.Double;

    // Clear previous data (if any)
    chart1.Series["Producao"].Points.Clear();

    // Add points to the chart
    foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
    {
        DateTime data = Convert.ToDateTime(row["pd_data"]);
        double quantidadeProduzida = Convert.ToDouble(row["pd_qtd_produzida"]);

        // Add the point (date, quantity) to the series
        chart1.Series["Producao"].Points.AddXY(data, quantidadeProduzida);
    }

    // Set the X axis label format to display only day and month
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy";

    // Set the angle of the labels on the X axis
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = -45;

    // Set the interval for the X axis labels (here set to 1 day)
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DateTimeIntervalType.Days;

    // Optional: Force the X axis boundary to start and end at the exact dates
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = chart1.Series["Producao"].Points[0].XValue;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = chart1.Series["Producao"].Points[chart1.Series["Producao"].Points.Count - 1].XValue;

    // Refresh the chart
    chart1.Invalidate();
}

